# jquery plans slider

Tags: jquery-ui, uislider

i need to design a plan slider for a web hosting design something like [this](http://static.livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_37867/) design . Please help.

Comment: What do you have so far?  Please show some initiative so we can help you with a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd point you to [this demo on jqueryui.com](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemax) but I'm in such a blind panic due to the urgency of your request that I've forgotten how to use a keyboard.